# java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10134 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android

I got a report of this exception from 1 user even though I have the permission in the manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see that not even one of the answer is related to your case(cuz you've correct permissions). I have gotten the same crash(4 crashes for now) for android 7 and 8 devices and have the correct internet and access_network_state permissions.

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem as well... when building against an earlier API, I was simply getting an `unhandledException` thrown, which I noticed when stepping over the `getAllNetworkInfo()` or `getActiveNetworkInfo()`. However, nothing was actually shown in logcat. When building against the newest API (22), I got the above-mentioned `SecurityException`.

For me, the solution turned out to be that I had written

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

when instead I needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

So, to any developer experiencing this issue and scratching his head, please note that these permission names are case sensitive!

Comment: permission that i mentioned in manifest is in small case only.

Answer (score 1):

I solved moving the uses-permission just below the manifest tag

Answer (score 0):

Your Permissions are right ,  Check **Null** Condition for **NetwrokInfo** Object  this might be the trick that causes crashing.(for those who  might face  this problem )

Answer (score 0):

Give this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```